# Cannot figure out how to set constructors and ABI for a contract

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, abi, constructor

So I've been breaking my head over this for the last 2 days. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the constructors and ABI set up properly.

I'm testing smart contracts by copying Sushi contract from here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b3595068778dd592e39a122f4f5a5cf09c90fe2#code

And then compiling and deploying on remix: https://remix.ethereum.org/

After I compile and go to the deploy tab and deploy, I don't see anything in the low level functions section here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J5cw.jpg

How do I set the owner, the symbol and all the other fields since they aren't hard coded in the solidity file?

I was also trying to do this on MEW and I deployed using bytecode output from remix and ABI shown on etherscan, but my deployed contract did not have an interface on etherscan to set these fields or show balanceOf method etc.

So how are these arguments passed and at what stage of the process? I've tried to google but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Name and Symbol are Hardcoded at the top of the SushiToken Contract.
2. The SushiToken uses Ownable and thus the owner is address that initialises the Token.
3. After deployment, you can connect back to your Smart Contract using the generated address that you get once you deploy the token. Regarding MEW, I have little experience,in using it. I mostly choose to use Remix or Truffle for Testing and Deployment.

Hope it helps, if you have other questions I will gladly reply If I know how to help.

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I started playing around with Truffle because that seems to be a good way to do this. When I run `truffle compile` I get multiple json files in the /contracts folder. Am I supposed to deploy each one of them separately? Most of them in Sushi are generic except the one with the name and symbol. How do I go from this compile to how the contract looks on ethereum blockchain. There I see a single file with the all the code.

Comment: Just saw that you actually use the `Address` interface instead of the MasterChef.
https://i.imgur.com/K87RHM5.png

Change the top side from `Address` to `MasterChef` or `SushiToken`

Comment: Regarding Truffle, you actually need to interact in step by step with all the Contracts similar to how the Sushi Owner did: https://medium.com/@dmitrydolgov_20222/sushideployer-f5f4fdb88e41